# HiddenField in UserControl returns null when I put code in separate file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol that contains a hiddenfield `<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfTotalCharacters" />`
 whitch store value from code behind. And some Javascript that reads that value. When I put the script inside the ascx file everything is working fine, but when I move the script in a .js file, I get a null object (second line):

```
    var hf = document.getElementById("<%=hfTotalCharacters.ClientID %>");
    alert(hf.value);
    var totalCharacters = hf.value
```

The reason that I must put the script in a separate file is because I want to use the userControl multiple times in the same page, but the moving is not working even in a one instance of the UC.
The JS file is loaded in the page, but the element can not found!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the js on another file, set the clientIdMode to static:

Like:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfTotalCharacters" ClientIDMode="static"/> 

var hf = document.getElementById("hfTotalCharacters");
alert(hf.value);
var totalCharacters = hf.value
```

Comment: well, thank you for your response, but as I said I want to use usercontrol many times and static is not allowed in this scenario.

Comment: How about calling wrapping the code in a function and calling it from the script

Comment: the above js lines are in the initialize() function already and are the very first commands of the js